# How to debug a sass file that doesn't reflect changes on the browser?

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm building a portfolio website using bootstrap and sass. I use a theme kit for it too. I wanted to do a grid column style for my intro-section but then changed my mind so I later deleted the style. But whenever I refresh my browser, I still get an error message. I have tried different things I could but couldn't make headway. The images are attached to this description.(I couldn't post any image. Says I need 10 reputation to do that.) Here's what I see on my style.css file:
content: "Error: Expected expression.\a    \2577 \a 13 \2502          grid-column: ;\d\a    \2502                       ^\a    \2575 \a   scss\sections\_intro-section.scss 13:22  @use\a   scss\style.scss 11:1                     root stylesheet";

I deleted the code and refreshed the browser it didn't work. I commented out the whole intro-section and refreshed my browser but that didn't work; it still showed me the same error message!
I deleted the error message from the style.css file but my browser didn't display as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It seems at first sight to be a cache issue, have you tried to clear your cache?

If that solves the issue you should look into file versioning/cache busting options for your compiler.
I don't know what compiler you are using otherwise i might have been able to help you further.

If cache busting doesn't solve it we have to look elsewhere. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick. Please which cache do you refer to here? Is it the browser cache?  Is it the browser cache? I have run the code using three different browsers. Maybe I'm missing something. Please I'll be grateful to have you explain further. I wish I could send a screenshot across.

Comment: Just to make 100% sure, can you check what happens if you open it in incognito mode? If the problem still persists in incognito then the cache is not the problem. In that case can you tell me what compiler you use and if it is giving any errors/warnings when you run it?